# Doing a secure ajax call over proxy creates new Session ID. How can I work around that?

Tags: php, ajax, session, proxy, cross-domain

I am working on a Zendesk app. It will allow end-users to integrate my own service in their Zendesk environment.

As they need to authenticate with my service, I decided to allow users to enter a token in the app's settings in Zendesk. This token won't be visible to all their agents using the app as it allows me to use *{{setting.token}}* in the code.

Now I am doing an ajax call (with *secure:true*) to authenticate the user and set *$_SESSION['userid']*. As I do not want to leak the token, the ajax call uses a proxy by Zendesk where the actual token is then added to the call.

So far so good! But since the proxy was used, the SessionID in login.php (url of ajax call) is different to the other pages. Hence *$_SESSION['userid']* can not be accessed on the other pages.

**My first work-around idea was the following:**

I added another custom-header the call, handing over the sessionID to login.php and setting it there before resuming the session.

This somehow works, but only when loading the page twice. When deleting the cookie and loading the page for the first time again, it does not work. Refreshing it then works again.

Can I get my workaround to work properly for the first time someone opens the page too?

Or should I approach this differently?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Same issue as me?**

Simply refresh the page after the ajax call response. Now the session variables will be available.